# Mathematica GUIKit

Tags: packages, gui-construction, java, deprecated

Does anyone of you know if the GUIKit package is still under some development by Wolfram Research or is the current version 1.1.0 the last one. Does it make sense to make GUIs using this package in case there is no further development?

Comment: The GUIKit was obsolete a very long time ago (on the introduction of *Mathematica* 6) and suffered from many bugs. A not-too-dissimilar alternative is David Bailey's [Super Widget Package](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/superwidgetpackage/superwidgetpackage.html), but it too is somewhat out-of-date, with the last update in November 2011. The implementation of the front end would tend to suggest that the `Dynamic` interface features are the ones to use now.